# What shape is the graph "Winnings" vs "Number of players with that amount of winnings" in this not-quite zero-sum game with lots of players?

Tags: normal-distribution, game-theory

I am interested in the following scenario:

A online/mobile app game is played by lots (for example, thousands, or millions) of people.

Each player starts with \$$20.$ A game is between two players and each player bets \$$1$ to play. The winner gets \$$2$ and the loser gets nothing. The app pairs players randomly (i.e. you don't know who your next opponent is).

Once a player hits zero, they are not allowed to continue playing (as they have nothing to bet).

My question is: After everyone plays lots and lots of games, what does the distribution of winnings look like?

I think if we assume the % win rate is a Normal distribution among the population with mean $50$% and standard deviation $4$%.

The $x-$ axis is the winnings to the nearest dollar and the $y$ axis is the number of people who won that amount of money to the nearest dollar. [If we didn't round to the nearest dollar then there wouldn't be many people who won the exact same amount, so the graph would be meaningless...]

The graph is convex decreasing with asymptote $y=0$ and I think $x=0$ is an asymptote also but I'm not sure. What is the graph? Is it $\ y=Ae^{-kx}?\quad y=k/x^n$ or something else, and why?

Comment: Did you simulate ? e.g. there are many data science tools in R to help you characterize the graph

Comment: Simulation is a good idea. Didn’t think of that

Comment: You could add tag guidance for “zero-sum”

Comment: @TymaGaidash I'm not sure what you mean. Please clarify.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Your question is the [only one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-sum?tab=Newest) with the “zero-sum” tag, so maybe you made it and can add usage guidance for it?

Comment: Yes I made it. How do you add usage guidance for it?

Comment: @TymaGaidash ah, now I get what you mean. If you have recently created a tag, you have to hover over the tag and then click "view tag" and then you can add usage guidance for it. I haven't done that before but just figured it out. Cheers.

Comment: Your question seems incomplete. If the player pool is fixed at start, as the opponents are chosen randomly, the winning rate is fixed, so the fortune of a given player follows a random walk (until one player is eliminated, which change the winning rate). Players with less than 1/2 winning rate are ruined almost surely, and at any point, there are some of them. So eventually, everyone will be ruined except one player. If we allow new players to enter the game, the distribution will be highly dependent on the rate at which new players enter the game...

Comment: @caduk I said, "after lots and lots of games", but I also mean, *well before* there are so many games that everyone bar one person is left standing. What I mean is, what does the time evolution of the distribution of winnings look like, from the first game played to the last game played? More interestingly, what do the winnings like "in the middle (time) of the start to the end" , like maybe when there are still $95$% of people remaining, what will the distribution of winnings look like?

Comment: I'd prefer `zero-sum-games`, or even better, `bimatrix-games` because the word "zero-sum" alone is prone to be abused by a lot of elementary-level questions or to refer to something completely unrelated to the game theory, e.g. "the sum of … is zero."